# Why I can't compare boolean to boolean in JavaScript React using Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Hello I'm working with [Flow](https://flow.org) to type checking my JavaScript code. 
My state for the following app looks like this:

```
type State = {
  todos: Array<{text: string, date: Object, completed: boolean}>,
};
```

After hit the command *flow start* I've got this error message: Cannot compare boolean to boolean.

The error message occurs at the following code snippet. There I toggle a todo item and I sort the list with a compare function.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({todos: t.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.completed === b.completed ? 0 : a.completed > b.completed ? -1 : a.completed < b.completed ? 1 : 0
})}));
```

Comment: It's either completed or not, so simple `a.completed === b.completed ? 1 : -1` would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't like that you are using the *relational comparison operator* with Boolean values.

```
1: true > false
   ^ Cannot compare boolean [1] to boolean [2].
    References:
    1: true > false
       ^ [1]
    1: true > false
              ^ [2]
```

https://flow.org/try/#0C4JwrgpgBAfFBmBDANgZwkA

---

If you wanted to sort completed items before uncompleted ones, you can do:

```
(a, b) => a.completed ? (b.completed ? 0 : -1) : 1
```

Or cast the values to numbers:

```
(a, b) => Number(b.completed) - Number(a.completed)
```